# Rewrite sql module

Tags: magento, module, url-rewriting, extend

Hi I'm trying to rewrite or extend all database update sql's files from **core** to **local** without success, until now I have:

**CORE:**

```
+core
 +Mage
  +Mymodule
   +...
   +etc
    -config.xml
   +sql
    +mymodule_setup
     -mysql4-install-0.1.0.php
     -mysql4-install-0.1.0-0.1.1.php
     -...
```

**LOCAL:**

```
+local
 +Mage
  +Mynamespace
   +Mymodule
    +...
    +etc
     -config.xml
    +sql
     +mymodule_setup
      -mysql4-install-0.1.0.php
      -mysql4-install-0.1.0-0.1.1.php
      -...
```

So my question is to avoid problems when upgrading Magento how show I configure the config.xml in **core** and **local**, rewrite **Block**, **Model**, I did with success, but not for sql, until now I have:

**LOCAL**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_Mymodule>
            <version>0.1.1</version>
        </Mage_Mymodule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <mynamespace_mymodule_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Mynamespace_Mymodule</module>
                    <class>Mage_Mymodule_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </mynamespace_mymodule_setup>
        </resources>
        <models>
            <Mymodule>
                <rewrite>
                    <abc>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Abc</abc>
                </rewrite>
            </Mymodule>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

> Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I don't understand, why are you using `local/Mage/Mynamespace/Mymodule/`? Sure the `Mage` part is superfluous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to override install/update scripts.
You have to:
1. Set dependency for your module, it must be installed last. 
2. In your install script you may use anything.
You'd better use Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you've changed the class in the resource setup to a class that probably doesn't exist. Try :

```
<setup>
   <module>Mynamespace_Mymodule</module>
   <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
</setup>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make some hack, like in your setup class overwrite the protected method _getAvailableDbFiles and rewriting it using dirname(**FILE**) instead of Mage::getModuleDir (Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup~480)